# component.set not working for picklist field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a number of lightning:inputField that i'm setting based on certain criteria, these all work except for picklist field types. The code below shows how i am setting the fields. The country field is the picklist and the 2 alerts have the correct value in them, however the value is not getting set on country. Is there a different method for setting picklist fields?

```
var address = res.getReturnValue();
var country = component.find('Country__c');
var pcodeFld = component.find('Postcode__c');

if(country != undefined){
 alert(country);
 alert(address.Country);
 country.set('v.value', address.Country);
}
if(pcodeFld != undefined){
 pcodeFld.set('v.value', address.Postcode);
}
```

EDIT: I can set a default value whilst using $A.createComponents using .set("v.value", "United Kingdom");

it just seems that i can't set it after the component has rendered based on some user action.

**Reproduceable Example:**

I just can't seem to set the value of any picklist fields when using `lightning:inputField`.

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:hasRecordId">
<div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" 
                                 recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                 objectApiName="Contact">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" aura:id="lastname"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
        <!--Picklist-->
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Country__c" aura:id="Country__c"/>
        <lightning:button label="Update" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.update}"/>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</div>    
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({    
    update: function(component, event, helper) {
        //alert(component.find("Country__c"));
       component.find("Country__c").set("v.value", "Ireland");
    },

})
```

Comment: Can you add markup as well, thanks. and is that lightning:input or lightning:inputField?

Comment: the markup is dynamically generated using $A.createComponents and theres a lot of it so its difficult to add here

Comment: does same code work if component is not dynamically ? There are few issues with setter when components are created using $A.createComponents. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196382/dynamically-created-selectoptions-not-appearing-in-dynamically-created-inputsele

Comment: No, I just tried with a non-dynamic lightning:inputfield and the value still doesnt get set

Comment: is your address.Country is in below format?

var opts = new Array();
opts.push({label: results.Name, value: results.Name});
component.set("v.options", opts);

If not then give label and Value in your Country

Comment: Just tried that as well and also no luck. Inspecting the element it looks like its being converted to a lightning:combobox, i cant see anywhere in the docs/google how to set the value of this from the controller

Comment: Probably a bug. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219250/did-they-break-lightninginput-with-summer18/219255#219255